# Parallelized image transformations using GraphicsMagick

Tags: performance, android, image, concurrency, shell

This is part of a script that I use for porting a TWRP theme from one resolution to another, respectively portrait to portrait and landscape to landscape. In this function entirely, it focuses on the images. What I am not showing is irrelevant since it focuses on porting the XML files.

I compiled [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org) for ARM and thus call on it when it is time to do the resizing of each image. GM can be a bit slow so I included a method which mimics the parallel concept to help speed up the process.

Is this sufficient or is there a better approach I can take given how this part of the script operates?

```
GOTOTWRPIMAGE() {

    NUM=0
    QUEUE=""
    MAX_NPROC=$(grep "processor :" < /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l) # default
    MAX_NPROC=$(($MAX_NPROC+1))

queue() {
    QUEUE="$QUEUE $1"
    NUM=$(($NUM+1))
}

regeneratequeue() {
    OLDREQUEUE=$QUEUE
    QUEUE=""
    NUM=0
    for PID in $OLDREQUEUE; do
        if [ -d /proc/$PID ]; then
            QUEUE="$QUEUE $PID"
            NUM=$(($NUM+1))
        fi
    done
}

checkqueue() {
    OLDCHQUEUE=$QUEUE
    for PID in $OLDCHQUEUE; do
        if [ ! -d /proc/$PID ]; then
            regeneratequeue # at least one PID has finished
            break
        fi
    done
}

    if [ ! -f "${P_IMAGES}"/image_dir.txt ]; then
        busybox touch "${P_IMAGES}"/image_dir.txt
    else
        rm -f "${P_IMAGES}"/image_dir.txt
        busybox touch "${P_IMAGES}"/image_dir.txt
    fi

    # Find the images to be ported.
    if output=$(find "${P_IMAGES}" -type f -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.jpg"); then
        echo "${output}" > "${P_IMAGES}"/image_dir.txt
    fi

    filename="${P_IMAGES}"/image_dir.txt
    filelines=$(cat "${filename}")

    for line in $filelines; do
        # Remember the directory and filename
        local IMAGEFILE="$(basename "${line}")"
        local IMAGEFILEDIR="$(dirname "${line}")"

        # Remember width and height
        SIZEW=$(gm identify -format "%w" "${IMAGEFILEDIR}"/"${IMAGEFILE}")
        SIZEH=$(gm identify -format "%h" "${IMAGEFILEDIR}"/"${IMAGEFILE}")

        # Calculate old size for new size of each image.
        # Round fractions up and down for each image.
        FINALW=$(awk 'BEGIN{print int("'$BASEW'"/("'$PORTW'"/"'$SIZEW'")+0.5)}')
        FINALH=$(awk 'BEGIN{print int("'$BASEH'"/("'$PORTH'"/"'$SIZEH'")+0.5)}')

        # Inform user of the change and conduct the change
        echo " "
        echo Porting "${IMAGEFILE}" from $SIZEW'x'$SIZEH to $FINALW'x'$FINALH
        # Convert image to new sizes
        gm convert -size  $FINALW'x'$FINALH! "${IMAGEFILEDIR}"/"${IMAGEFILE}" -resize $FINALW'x'$FINALH! "${IMAGEFILEDIR}"/"${IMAGEFILE}" &

        PID=$!
        queue $PID

        while [ $NUM -ge $MAX_NPROC ]; do
            checkqueue
            #sleep 0.4
        done
    done
    wait # wait for all processes to finish before exit

    if [ -f "${P_IMAGES}"/image_dir.txt ]; then
        rm -rf "${P_IMAGES}"/image_dir.txt
    fi

    if [ $OPT == "1" ]; then
        HEADSUP
    fi
}
```